# Как подсчитать записи в таблице за день по timestamp?

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть поле time (тип int), которое хранит временну́ю метку в формате *timestamp*.

Как подсчитать записи в таблице за текущий день?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)),  COUNT(*)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY time;
```

Полезные ссылки:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970938/group-by-day-from-timestamp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column
- http://reisub.blogspot.nl/2011/04/mysql-now.html
- http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/mysql-select-from-table-where-date-today/

Comment: `DATE(datetime) ` разве конвертирует timestamp в date`

Comment: а где группировку потеряли?

Comment: @Kaffarov, уже добавил )) спасибо вам за внимательность =)

Comment: Не работает - всегда пустой результат

Comment: Мне нужен интервал за день - а не чтобы все значения поля datetime были равны текущему дню

Comment: @Kaffarov, не совсем понял про интервал? В смысле нужно не за сегодня, а за последние 24 часа?

Comment: а если WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = CURDATE() ?

Comment: для 24 часов WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541205/counting-rows-where-a-timestamp-is-less-than-24-hours-old

Answer (score 1):

чуть более общее решение. первый запрос — количество строк за текущий день, второй — сами строки за текущий день, третий запрос — строки за любой произвольный день.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5695b/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (time int);

insert into t values
  (unix_timestamp ('2015-01-01 11:00')),
  (unix_timestamp ('2015-01-02 12:00')),
  (unix_timestamp ('2015-01-03 13:00')),
  (unix_timestamp (current_timestamp()));
```

**Query 1**:

```
select count(*) as count_lines
from t
where time >= unix_timestamp (curdate())
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5695b/5/0)**:

```
| count_lines |
|-------------|
|           1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select from_unixtime (time) as time
from t
where time >= unix_timestamp (curdate())
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5695b/5/1)**:

```
|                   time |
|------------------------|
| July, 22 2015 08:26:09 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select from_unixtime (time) as time
from t
where time between
  unix_timestamp ('2015-01-02') and
  unix_timestamp ('2015-01-03')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5695b/5/2)**:

```
|                      time |
|---------------------------|
| January, 02 2015 12:00:00 |
```

Comment: Вы не отвечаете на вопрос! Нужно посчитать количество строк. И условие `>=`.

Comment: @pavelip, и в самом деле, слона-то я и не заметил. спасибо. добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Мы избавляемся от преобразования для каждой строки, вычисляя время начала суток в единицах `timestamp`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   TestTable
WHERE  time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

Для вычисления количества нам не нужна группировка с преобразованием.

В этом запросе может использоваться индекс по полю `time`.